# Prepared statement not sending to database. Thinking img file upload may be a part of issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, prepared-statement

I am attempting to create my first prepared statement and am having troubles with getting the data to send to the db. I am trying to send product info and send an img file to a folder and then move the permanent file name to my db.

As of now none of the data sends to my db. The only thing that send is my picture file to my productpics folder. I've tried to do this myself as far as I can and I have been stuck on this for a long time.

Does anyone see anything wrong in my code with the prepared statement or with how I'm trying to send the img file that would be causing this to not send?

The only error I have is for the $date variable I have right underneath of this. I'm not too worried about that unless it is causing this to not work. The error I am getting is being acquired from php error reporting.

I validate everything but the img file above this code.

```
//Create
 $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    if($validation->passed()) {
        if(isset($_POST['create'])){ 
            $product_id = trim( $_POST['product_id'] );
            $name = trim( $_POST['name'] );
            $price = trim( $_POST['price'] );
            $saleprice = trim( $_POST['saleprice'] );
            $final_price = trim( $_POST['final_price'] );
            $shippingprice = trim( $_POST['shippingprice'] );
            $category = trim( $_POST['category'] );
            $item_details = trim( $_POST['item_details'] );
            $item_details2 = trim( $_POST['item_details2'] );
            $description = trim( $_POST['description'] );
            $viewproduct_type = trim( $_POST['viewproduct_type'] );
            $date = ( $_POST['date_created'] );
            $file = "productpics/". $_FILES['file']['name']; // save the filename

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file); // move the file

        //Connection
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");
        /* check connection */
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }



        /* create a prepared statement */
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO products ('product_id', 'name', 'price', 'saleprice', 'final_price', 'shippingprice', 'category', item_details', 'item_details2', 'description', 'viewproduct_type', 'date', 'img') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {


            /* bind parameters for markers */
            $stmt->bind_param('isiiiisssssis', $product_id, $name, $price, $saleprice, $final_price, $shippingprice, $category, $item_details, $item_details2, $description, $viewproduct_type, $date, $file);

            /* execute query */
            $stmt->execute();


        /* close statement */
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            }
        }
    }
 }
}   
?>
```

The form

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="product_id">Product ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="product_id" class="smallinputbar" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="name">Product Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="price">Product Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="price" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="saleprice">Sale Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="saleprice">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="final_price">Final Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="final_price" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="shippingprice">Shipping Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="shippingprice" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="category" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="item_details">Item Details</label>
        <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="item_details" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="item_details2">Item Details 2</label>
        <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="item_details2">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="description" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="viewproduct_type">View Product Type</label>
        <select class="optionbar" name="viewproduct_type">
            <option name="notSelected">Not Selected</option>
            <option name="viewproduct_type" value="a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id">Standard</option>
            <option name="viewproduct_type" value="Option">Option</option>
        </select>
    </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
            <label for="button">
            <input type="submit" id="button" name="create" value="Create New Product">
            </label>

        <span class="floatright">
            <input type="file" name="file" class="inputbarfile">
            <input type="submit" name="create" id="signinButton" value="Upload">
        </span>
</form>
```

Any ideas why this isn't sending?

UPDATED CODE:

```
//Create

    if($validation->passed()) {
        if(isset($_POST['create'])){ 
            $product_id = trim( $_POST['product_id'] );
            $name = trim( $_POST['name'] );
            $price = trim( $_POST['price'] );
            $saleprice = trim( $_POST['saleprice'] );
            $final_price = trim( $_POST['final_price'] );
            $shippingprice = trim( $_POST['shippingprice'] );
            $category = trim( $_POST['category'] );
            $item_details = trim( $_POST['item_details'] );
            $item_details2 = trim( $_POST['item_details2'] );
            $description = trim( $_POST['description'] );
            $viewproduct_type = trim( $_POST['viewproduct_type'] );
            $file = "productpics/". $_FILES['file']['name']; // save the filename

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file); // move the file

        //Connection
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");
        /* check connection */
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }



        /* create a prepared statement */
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO products (product_id, name, price, saleprice, final_price, shippingprice, category, item_details, item_details2, description, viewproduct_type, date, img) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), ?)")) {


            /* bind parameters for markers */
            $stmt->bind_param('isiiiissssss', $product_id, $name, $price, $saleprice, $final_price, $shippingprice, $category, $item_details, $item_details2, $description, $viewproduct_type, $file);

            /* execute query */
            $stmt->execute();


        /* close statement */
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            }
        }
    }
 }
}   
?>
```

I then removed the name part in the option.
    
        View Product Type
        
            Not Selected
            Standard
            Option

Comment: `The error I am getting is being acquired from php error reporting. ` What's that error?

Comment: I did notice this though, you're declaring `$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` then overwriting with `$date = ( $_POST['date_created'] );` where that input doesn't exist.

Comment: I took that out as you suggested before. In my question if you look to where it says 'Updated Code' that is what it looks like now.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the incorrect identifier qualifiers for your column names, being single quotes `'`

Either remove them, or replace them with ticks.

Ticks example:

```
(`product_id`, `name`, `price`, `saleprice`, `final_price`,  
`shippingprice`, `category`, item_details`, `item_details2`, 
`description`, `viewproduct_type`, `date`, `img`)
```

Checking for errors would have signaled the syntax errors.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Replace `$stmt->execute();` with

`if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$con->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` and you will see the syntax errors.

References:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

---

Plus, only `<select>` bears the name attribute and not `<option>`. `<option>` should contain "value"`.

Comment: I replaced that as you said to and I am still getting the same errors as I was before. The error with my date variable being... Notice: Undefined index: date_created in /home4/pfarley1/public_html/addproduct.php on line 89.....and another undefined variable I have close to the end of the page....

Comment: So you are saying to do this... 'product_id, name, price,

Comment: @Paul ticks `\`` are not the same as `'` regular quotes, as I edited my answer. Either use "ticks" or remove them, as also stated in my answer.  as for `Notice: Undefined index: date_created` you don't have an input bearing the name attribute `date_created` and that's why you're getting that warning.

Comment: @Paul another thing, only `<select>` bears the name attribute and not `<option>` which you have for it. Something else I just spotted now. `<option>` should contain "value"`

Comment: I removed the ' regular quotes and it still isn't sending anything. Could my undefined index for my date be causing this to not send?

Comment: @Paul exactly, if one fails, your query will fail. either assign a date-related option for it, or remove it.

Comment: I won't be having a form option for it. So can I I replace one of the prepare ?'s and put in the NOW() function like this... ?, ?, NOW(), ?

Comment: @Paul as a matter of fact I was just about to suggest that. but the `i` for it might give you problems.

Comment: @Paul and if you use `NOW()` make sure the column is of `datetime`  type or similar. Consult the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: I'm still confused with what to do with this... $date = ( $_POST['date_created'] );   ..... I don't have form data for it, so will just deleting this and just having the Now() work in the prepared statement?

Comment: @Paul yes delete it and get rid of the `$date` variable in the the bind, as well as the `i` in the bind_param but keep the `date` for the column, assuming you do have a column for it, I hope.

Comment: Okay, I took the date fields out you mentioned. Still, nothing is sending to my db.

Comment: @Paul look in my answer under `Replace $stmt->execute(); with` the line under that. Replace it with that line below and will signal errors if any. I have to go to bed now. If that doesn't help you, I will have to delete my answer.

Comment: Didn't throw any errors. I appreciate you trying to help